# Replace characters in a column, based on a translation table from another data frame

Tags: r, replace

I have a `data.frame` `mapping` which contains path and map. 
I also have another `data.frame` `DATA` which contains the raw path and value.
EDIT: Path might have two components or more: e.g. "A>C" or "A>C>B"

```
set.seed(24);
DATA <- data.frame(
            path=paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 25, replace=TRUE), ">", sample(LETTERS[1:3], 25, replace=TRUE)),
            value=rnorm(25)
        )
mapping <- data.frame(path=c("A","B","C"), map=c("X","Y","Z"))

lapply(mapping, function (x) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(DATA)) {
    DATA$path[i] <- gsub(as.character(x["path"]),as.character(x["map"]),as.character(DATA$path[i]))    
  }
})
```

I'm trying to replace the path in `DATA` with the map value in `mapping` but this doesn't seem to be working for me.

"A>C" will be converted to "X>Z".

I understand that for loops are not good in `R`, but I can't think of another way to code it. Data size I'm working with is 6m row in `DATA` and 16k rows in `mapping`.

**Clarification on Data**: While the path consists of alphabets (ABC) now, the real path are actually domain names. Number of steps in a path is also not fixed at 2 and can be any number.

Comment: Could you give a quick example of your desired output? e.g. would "A>C" be converted to "X>Z"?

Comment: yes that is correct. "A>C" will be converted to "X>Z" according to the mapping table.

Comment: Seems to me it would be simpler if you keep `path_from` and `path_to` as separate columns. Then apply mapping to both columns. Also, why not make mapping a `hash`, then you just look it up?

Comment: @smci, while that will work, path is not always length of 2, meaning it can be A > B > C etc. I am also familiar with hash in other languages, just didn't know there's one for R!

Comment: @iukie: Ok, but you didn't state that crucial requirement ;-) In that case, yeah, you could split path on '>' and do string substitution (by hash or chartr). But if there is a modest upper bound on the number of path components (e.g. 20), then it may still make sense to store them separately (use NA after you reach the end of the path components). Depends on how much processing of path components you do.

Comment: 'hash', 'translation dictionary', sounds like the way to go for doing the mapping.

Comment: @smci, I wish there's a upper bound too but unfortunately, real world data is seldom that neat. There'll probably be an outlier that's more than 100 steps long. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chartr`

```
  DATA$path <- chartr('ABC', 'XYZ', DATA$path)
```

Or if we are using the data from 'mapping'

```
  DATA$path <- chartr(paste(mapping$path, collapse=''), 
                    paste(mapping$map, collapse=''), DATA$path)
```

---

Or using `gsubfn`

```
  library(gsubfn)
  pat <- paste0('[', paste(mapping$path, collapse=''),']')
  indx <- setNames(as.character(mapping$map), mapping$path)
  gsubfn(pat, as.list(indx), as.character(DATA$path))
```

---

Or a `base R` option based on @smci's comment

```
  vapply(strsplit(as.character(DATA$path), '>'), function(x) 
                 paste(indx[x], collapse=">"), character(1L))
```

Comment: Fancy pants. I still think @smci 's comment is the right way to go though, in terms of separating the data.

Comment: I understand the process, I just think if you're going to have `from-to` data, you're better off having two separate columns.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, that is also another way.

Comment: There's an obvious benefit to keeping the path components separate: we can use NA for any missing/ invalid/ untranslated components. Can't do that if you string-join the components.

Comment: @smci Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` (`1.9.5+`), especially advisable b/c of the size of your data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA); setDT(mapping)
DATA[,paste0("path",1:2):=tstrsplit(path,split=">")]
setkey(DATA,path1)[mapping,new.path1:=i.map]
setkey(DATA,path2)[mapping,new.path2:=i.map]
DATA[,new.path:=paste0(new.path1,">",new.path2)]
```

If you want to get rid of the extra columns:

```
DATA[,paste0(c("","","new.","new."),"path",rep(1:2,2)):=NULL]
```

If you just want to overwrite `path`, use `path` on the LHS of the last line instead of `new.path`.

This could also be written more concisely:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mapping)
setkey(setkey(setDT(DATA)[,paste0("path",1:2):=tstrsplit(path,split=">")
                          ],path1)[mapping,new.path1:=i.map],path2
       )[mapping,new.path:=paste0(new.path1,">",i.map)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong apply.

mapply allows you to use two arguments to the function, here the path and the map. Note that in mapply, the argument FUN comes first. You also do not need to do this row by row, you can just do the entire column at once. Finally, in an apply the variables do not get updated as they do in a for loop, so you need to assign them in the .GlobalEnv. You can do this with an explicit call to assign() or using <<- which assigns them in the first place it finds them in the stack. In this case, that will be back in .GlobalEnv.

After defining mapping and DATA as you do above, try this.

```
head(DATA)
invisible(mapply( function (x,y) {
  DATA$path <<- gsub(x,y,DATA$path)    
},mapping$path, mapping$map))

head(DATA)
```

note that the call to invisible suppresses output from mapply.

If you really want to use lapply, you can. But you need to transpose mapping. You can do that but it will be converted to a matrix, so you have to convert it back. Then, you can just use the same tricks with <<- and not using a for loop as above to get this code:

```
invisible(lapply(as.data.frame(t(mapping)), function (x) {
   DATA$path <<- gsub(x[1],x[2],DATA$path)    
}))
head(DATA)
```

Thanks for sharing, I learned a lot answering this question.